# How to throw custom exception from cartcontroller?

Tags: magento-1.9, exception

```
public function addAction()
{
    if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        $this->_goBack();
        return;
    }
    $cart   = $this->_getCart();
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $h=1;
    try {
        if($h==1){
            die("here.......");
        }
        if (isset($params['qty'])) {
            $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
            );
            $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
        }

        $product = $this->_initProduct();
        $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

        /**
         * Check product availability
         */
        if (!$product) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }

        $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        if (!empty($related)) {
            $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
        }

        $cart->save();

        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

        /**
         * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
         */
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
        );

        if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
            if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()) {
                $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
            }
            $this->_goBack();
        }
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
            $this->_getSession()->addNotice(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
        } else {
            $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($message));
            }
        }

        $url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
        if ($url) {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        } else {
            $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.'));
        Mage::logException($e);
        $this->_goBack();
    }
}
```

> here from the die portion how can i throw my custom exception for a error message?thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to throw an exception. Where $error is the string.

```
Mage::throwException($error);
```